# Странности в определении типа речи

Tags: типы-речи

Почему эксперты считают, что здесь "представлено **рассуждение**"?

> (12)Но уж давно известно, что самые прекрасные и полезные истины,
> исходящие из уст господина лесницына, господина агронома и других
> интеллигентных радетелей, представляют для деревни лишь простое
> сотрясение воздуха. (13)На другой же день добрые поселяне пускали в
> лес скот, объедавший дочиста молодняк, драли лыко с нежных, неокрепших
> деревьев, валили для какого-нибудь забора или оконницы строевые ели,
> просверливали стволы берёз для вытяжки весеннего сока на квас, курили
> в сухостойном лесу и бросали спички на серый высохший мох,
> вспыхивающий как порох, оставляли непогашенными костры. (14)Он
> упрашивал сельских учителей внедрять ученикам уважение и любовь к
> лесу, подбивал их вместе с деревенскими батюшками, — и, конечно,
> бесплодно, — устраивать праздники лесонасаждения, приставал к
> исправникам, земским начальникам и мировым судьям по поводу
> хищнических порубок, а на земских собраниях так надоел всем своими
> пылкими речами о защите лесов, что его перестали слушать.